# Python 3.5 loop to generate a new list each iteration

Tags: list, loops, random, python-3.5

I'm trying to write some code that (pseudo-randomly) generates a list of 7 numbers. I have it working for a single run. I'd like to be able to loop this code to generate multiple lists, which I can output to a txt file (I don't need help with this I'm quite comfortable working with i/o and files :)

I'm now using this code (thanks Jason for getting it this far):

```
import random

pool = []
original_pool = list( range( 1,60))

def selectAndPrune(x):
        pool = []
        list1 = []
        random.shuffle(pool)
        pool = original_pool.copy()
        current_choice = random.choice(pool)
        list1.append(current_choice)
        pool.remove(current_choice)
        random.shuffle(pool)
        print(list1)

def repeater():
    for i in range(19):
        pool_list = []
        pool = original_pool.copy()
        a = [ selectAndPrune(pool) for x in range(7)]
        pool_list.append(a)

repeater()
```

This is giving output of single value lists like:

```
[21]
[1]
[54]
[48]
[4]
[32]
[15]
etc.
```

The output I want is 19 lists, all containing 7 random ints:

```
[1,4,17,23,45,51,3] 
[10,2,9,38,4,1,24]
[15,42,35,54,43,28,14]
etc
```

Comment: You are trying to create 19 sub-lists that each has length of 7 (total 133 elements). But every iteration you are removing one element from the pool (at the start 59 elements), so that's why you get the error.

Comment: True. If you change the range to (2) the code appends the same list rather than generating a new list of 7 numbers. I want to create a new list with each pass, and reset the pool (now you've mentioned it!)

Answer (score 1):

If I am understanding the question correctly, the objective is to repeat a function 19 times. However, this function slowly removes items from the list at each call, making it impossible to run past the size of the pool **as currently written in the question**. I suspect that the solution is something like this:

```
import random

def spinAndPrune():
    random.shuffle( pool )
    current_choice = random.choice( pool )
    pool.remove( current_choice )
    random.shuffle( pool )
    return current_choice
```

First, I added a return command at the end of the function call. Next, you can make copy of the original pool, so that it is possible to re-run it as many times as desired. Also, you need to store the lists you want to keep:

```
# create an original pool of values
original_pool = list( range( 1, 60 ) )

# initialize a variable that stores previous runs
pool_list = []

# repeat 19 times
for i in range( 19 ):

    # create a copy of the original pool to a temporary pool
    pool = original_pool.copy()

    # run seven times, storing the current choice in variable a
    a = [ spinAndPrune() for x in range( 7 ) ]

    # keep track of variable a in the pool_list
    pool_list.append( a )
    print( a )
```

Note the `.copy()` function to make a copy of the list. As an aside, the `range()` makes it easy to create lists containing integers 1-59.

If you need to extract a specific list, you can do something along the lines of this:

```
# print first list
print( pool_list[ 0 ] )

# print fifth list
print( pool_list[ 4 ] )

# print all the lists
print( pool_list )
```

Comment: You are understanding it thanks Jason. I wish I'd have thought of the range thing in the list declaration! I get your idea, however this still gives the same error. It also doesn't output multiple lists of 7, it continues to append the output list so it's > 7

Comment: Ok, I misunderstood the output. Apparently, you want to track the seven random numbers, not the remaining 59-7 list. See the modifications to my answer

Comment: List1 is the output list yes, and I want output of 19 separate sets of 7 numbers:
[1,2,5,36,47,53,35]
[55,3,15,36,7,5,3]
etc
Your code is interesting to read however I'm getting local var 'pool' referenced before assignment so not sure if it works!

Comment: Ah so i've modded the code so that it works (moved list delarations inside of functions - the output is giving me a vertical line of single ints like: [34]. So it looks like the end output list only contains 1 value, where I want y values.

Answer (score 0):

In my other answer, I approached it by modifying the code in the original question. However, if the point is just to extract X number of values without repeat in a collection/list, it is probably easiest to just use the `random.sample()` function. The code can be something along the lines of this:

```
import random

pool = list( range( 1, 60 ) )
pool_list = []

# sample 19 times and store to the pool_list
for i in range( 19 ):
    sample = random.sample( pool, 7 )
    pool_list.append( sample )
    print( sample )
```

Comment: I've made an edit to the OP that I hope will make my desired output clearer. I can see what you're doing with it, it's not quite giving me the output I need but I think you're nearly there! This is looking better than my original code :)

Comment: I modified this answer again. If your only goal is to print the values to match what you requested in the question, then it's even simpler because you can remove the two `pool_list` lines.

Comment: I've edited the question and replaced the code with what I'm using thanks to your efforts. I think it just makes it clearer - sorry I didn't explain very well first time.

Comment: I just modified both my answers to print what you want. Good luck figuring it out